# 403 error; won't proxy: NginX and Node.js

Tags: nginx, node.js

I currently have a setup where all static files are served by NginX, and if no static file is found it is moved onto a node.js server.  Unfortunately I am getting a 403 error for the root request.  Everything else is working fine.

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    error_page 404 = /404.html;
    root /web/sites/this.site.tld/static;
    index home;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
    }

    location @proxy {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_X_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://thisSiteApp;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}

upstream thisSiteApp{
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}
```

I am fairly sure the problem lies with the index directive.  Placing a "index.html" file in static and changing the directive to "index index.html" works.  But what I really want to do is make it look to the node server for the index location, while still serving my static files without looking at node.

NB. If I put the proxy settings under the / location the node server serves the root just fine (well without the static files, but it serves its part fine).

Comment: I have a "work around", where I use a "location = / {...proxy details}" as well as the other two.  Of course this will not serve any index file I place in the static directory (which I would do when the app is down for maintenance for example).

Answer (score 4):

Your try_files directive has a forward slash, so nginx will try to serve the directory when just going to the bare root of `example.org/`.

Instead of:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
}
```

use:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @proxy;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First sorry for my bad english, I think I undestand your problem And you need to do some think like this:

Define fist your static contect:

```
location ~ \.(jpg|png|etc)$ {

root  /web/sites/this.site.tld/static;
}
```

And then make a proxy pass to your node js server

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
  }
```

Or your method:
 location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
    }

```
location @proxy {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_X_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://thisSiteApp;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

}

upstream thisSiteApp{

Or something like that.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't answer the question